# why has author divided by 1.5 in hands on machine learning with scikit learn

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, data-transformation, dataset, algorithms

I am reading [Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow](http://index-of.es/Varios-2/Hands%20on%20Machine%20Learning%20with%20Scikit%20Learn%20and%20Tensorflow.pdf) (76/718), and the author is talking about dividing the dataset into a test set which i follow, but then goes on to talk about strata with this test set, and divides median household income by `1.5`.

Can anyone help out as to why he has divided by `1.5` it is really bugging me because he has not explained it! I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: The author explain it: "to limit the number of income
categories". Have you tried removing the 1.5 factor ? what did it do ?

Answer (score 0):

As the author states in the text, because there is a long tail of incomes on the right side of the distribution, he divided by 1.5 in order to "concentrate" that long tail inside 1-2 categories and to avoid having a lot of  bins with very few datapoints because of the tail.
Why by 1.5? It is somewhat arbitrary: probably he got that number by rule of thumb or trial and error until he got the desired number of compact categories.